# Geting fully qualified URL in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

How can I generate a fully-qualified URL (including protocol and port) outside of a web request context (i.e. in a Model property getter)?

For example, I have a model as follows:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_published = models.BooleanField()
    release_notes_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    @property
    def package_url(self):
        return <<some root url>> + "/foo/" + self.filename
```

From `package_url` I'd like to get that full qualified URL.

Comment: Did you try `return reverse('namespace:name', args=[self.filename])`?

Comment: What does that have to do with HTTP?

Comment: I may have misunderstood - are you trying to generate an absolute URL? If so, I was providing information based on: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Comment: I don't want the URL for an object. I want the base URL of the web application itself. I'm asking for the url *in* the model, not *of* the model ;)

Comment: @MarkRichman Can you explain your use case a bit more? e.g. how you plan on using the `package_url` property. I suppose you could create some "home" url in urls.py tied to a view and use `reverse` to that home view in a similar way as Hybrid described.

Comment: That information isn't going to **exist** outside of a web request context. I'm not sure what your use case is but is it possible to set a fully qualified ABS_ROOT_URL in your app settings? Or do you have different URLs coming into your app?

Comment: I suppose I can put something in settings, but I was hoping there was a dynamic approach. I'm porting an ASP.NET application, and I use a combination of `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority` to construct the URL prefix. Where `Authority` is something like "localhost:8888" and the former is the name of the web application.

Comment: I would probably just have a get_abs_url function on the model, that takes the request object as an argument. Then you can get the needed url pieces from the request.